# Wrong number format after filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, number-formatting

One of my Wordpress plugin output a price, I want to alter this price with the integrated filter. Here is the source:

```
$price_str = apply_filters( 'price_format', number_format($price,0,'', '.') );
```

Add I have added this filter:

```
   function change_price( $price ) {
    $price = $price * 2;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'price_format', 'change_price', 10, 1 );
```

If the price was 45.000 (Forty Five Thousand) it not becomes 90 (Ninety), I want it to be 90.000.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PHP takes "45.000" to mean "45", as the dot is the decimal delimiter, while your price uses it to indicate thousands (which some countries to, and they'll use the comma to separate decimals).

```
function change_price( $price ) {
    $price = str_replace(".", "", $price);
    $price = $price * 2;
    return number_format($price,0, '', '.');
}
add_filter( 'price_format', 'change_price', 10, 1 );
```

Will work in that case, first removing the thousand seperator, doing the calculation and adding it again in the same format it was originally.

Be aware that if you do have prices that are not integers (think 45000.99), this will round the price to the nearest integer because number_format's third parameter is empty. You can't do a lot about this, since it already occurs in the original function that is applying the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function change_price( $price ) {
    $price = floatval($price) * 2;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'price_format', 'change_price', 10, 1 );
```